# Kendo UI & Codeigniter - DataSource - Read - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: codeigniter, kendo-ui

I'm new in Kendo UI & Codeigniter. I have trouble with Kendo UI when i trying to read data from codeigniter controller. 
I can see json data, which is return from controller, but it not display at Kendo UI grid. Below is some screen shoot when i'm debug.

Here is screen shot error
http://prntscr.com/5bmn3n

Here is screen shot data i recived
http://prntscr.com/5bmne5

Here is screen shot Kendo UI code:
prntscr.com/5bmnib

And here is screen shot my controller code:
prntscr.com/5bmnni

Hope you can help

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to add

`transport: {
   read: { 
   ...
   dataType: "json"
   ...
         }
  },`

Also, please have in mind that "jsonp" is required for cross-domain requests!

Comment: Hi Hirikakis, thank for your answer
I have already try as your comment. But it the same problem as i mention in the question :(

Here is my screen shot about kendo script as your comment
http://prntscr.com/5dqvhl